# How Can I Make An HTML File Edit A File On The Server?

Tags: html, edit

I would like to make a file that monitors the page views of my web pages, and to do so I would need to make my web paages be able to edit this file.  I'm not too good at JavaScript or PHP, so I'm not dsure how to do this, if its possible.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: 3rd-party Web Analytics anyone?  Why roll your own when there are lots of good solutions out there?  For example, [AWStats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWStats) is pretty nice for an on-site solution, or [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) for completely managed service.

Comment: You will have to do it with either JavaScript or PHP. HTML in itself is a mark up language, not so much a 'programming' language in the normal sense of the word. Or you can use an analytics service, maybe http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to solve your issue it to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). If you don't want to do that, then the second easiest way is to use PHP.

Something like:

```
 <?php 
 $file = "vistors.txt"; 

 $handle = fopen($file, 'r+') ; 

 $data = fread($handle, 512) ; 

 $count = $data + 1;
 print "You are visitor ".$count; 
 ?>
```

Right at the top of your php file would do the job. This isn't great, though as it leads to a read and write on every page load, even for Googlebot, or other similar things.

The rest of the page has to wait for this to happen as well, so if things take a while, then the page will slow down.

I have written my own analytics, which uses AJAX (because it's async) to insert data into a MYSQL database. This has a lot more functionality.

Most people just use Google Analytics though, as it provides tons of features.

Answer (score 0):

HTML files cannot modify anything, period, because they are not executables or scripts, they cannot do anything, things are done to them. To do something like that you would need a script or a program, PHP, JavaScript and ASP.NET come to mind. You could, theoretically, write a mod for your HTTP server, to track page requests, but that is grossly overcomplicated. Depending on what you need the statistics for, you can use a [visit counter](https://www.google.ru/search?rls=en&q=page%20visit%20counter) or a web analytics tool like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).